# How do I remove grid lines from a Bokeh plot?

Tags: python, bokeh

I would like to remove the grid lines from a Bokeh plot.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Have a look at the [Bokeh line styling documentation](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#lines)

You can hide the lines by setting their `grid_line_color` to `None`.

```
fig.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
fig.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
```

Comment: Note that the documentation for styling lines in the latest release version is here: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#lines

Answer (score 30):

An alternative way to hide the lines is:

```
p.xgrid.visible = False
p.ygrid.visible = False
```

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#visible-property

It might be faster, but I didn't check it out.

Answer (score 5):

You can write

```py
p.grid.visible = False
```

which will make both `xgrid` and `ygrid` invisible at the same time.

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#styling-grids